# Parse error dado ao verificar variáveis com a função empty()

Tags: php, empty

Estou com um probleminha no meu PHP quando passo mais de uma variável para ele verificar separado por virgula ele gera um parse error.

**Olhem meu código abaixo:**

```php
if (isset($_POST['btnCriaTempo'])){

  $ordem         = trim($_POST['ordem']);
  $timeHours     = trim($_POST['tempoHora']);
  $timeMinutes   = trim($_POST['tempoMinuto']);
  $timeSeconds   = trim($_POST['tempoSegundo']);
  $visao         = trim($_POST['visibilidade']);
  $momentHours   = trim($_POST['momentoHora']);
  $momentMinutes = trim($_POST['momentoMinuto']);
  $momentSeconds = trim($_POST['momentoSegundo']);

  if (!empty($ordem, $visao)){ /*Esta é a linha 41*/

    $sqlCriaTempo = "INSERT INTO sv_tempo (tempoTotal, tempoVisao, tempoMomento, tempoOrdem)"
                    ." values (:tempoTotal, :tempoVisao, :tempoMomento, :tempoOrdem)";

    $queryCriaTempo = $conecta->prepare();
  }
}
```

Dá esse erro:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
in C:\xampp\htdocs\newcemp\admin\create\tempo.php on line 41
```

Sou eu que estou errando a sintaxe mesmo? Quando coloco só um roda normal.

Comment: Acredito que o `empty()` não suporta varias variaveis como `isset()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O teu problema é que a função [`empty()`](http://pt2.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.empty.php) só aceita um argumento, ou seja, só podes verificar uma variável de cada vez.

Uma ideia é criar uma função que receba múltiplos argumentos que por cada argumento recebido vai chamar a função `empty()` e realizar a verificação:

```php
function mempty() {

  foreach (func_get_args() as $arg) {

    if (empty($arg)) {
      continue;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

<sup>Créditos para a solução dados ao utilizador imkingdavid do StackOverflow [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7798842/352449).</sup>

---

A alternativa é validar variável a variável:

```php
if (!empty($ordem) && !empty($visao)) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: Vlw a melhor resposta... Obrigado!

Answer (score 9):

Sim, a função *empty* só aceita um parâmetro. Veja o manual da função [`empty()`](https://www.php.net/empty) no site oficial.

```
bool empty ( mixed $var )
```

Este *mixed* significa que aceita vários tipos de dados para o parâmetro `$var`.

Lá tem alguns exemplos de como fazer funções derivadas para verificar vários itens ao mesmo tempo. Talvez não tenha exatamente para o que você quer, mas é bem fácil fazer uma função que aceite vários parâmetros e verifique se todos estão vazios. Mas já é outro problema.

Você deve mudar o `if` para:

```
if (!empty($ordem) && !empty($visao)) {
```

[Coloquei no **Github** para futura referência](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/Empty.php).

Comment: Obrigado pela força!!!